# can i use different lambdas for a call to std::sort depending on a condition?

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda

right now i have three separate calls to std::sort, and they work, but is it possible to squeeze the code down a bit more? some thing like

```
const char *order;
vector<game_s*> gms;    // an elsewhere-filled vector of pointers to game structs, which themselves contain
                        // an opponent name and two timestamps, among other members

sometype cmp;           // how to declare lambda function?

if      (! strcmp(order, "by name"))
    cmp = [] (game_s* g1, game_s *g2) { return strcmp(g1->opp,      g2->opp)    < 0; };

else if (! strcmp(order, "by_start"))
    cmp = [] (game_s* g1, game_s *g2) { return strcmp(g1->starttm,  g2->starttm)< 0; };

else if (! strcmp(order, "by_end"))
    cmp = [] (game_s* g1, game_s *g2) { return strcmp(g1->endtm,    g2->endtm)  < 0; };

else        { cout << '"' << order << '"' << " is not a valid sort order."; return; }

sort(gms.begin(), gms.end(), cmp);
```

Comment: The `sometype` you're looking for is [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you use C-style null-terminated strings in your `game_s` structure instead of `std::string`?

Comment: And why not call `std::sort` in each case? There's really no practical difference from what you show. In fact, it's even *more* code now, since you need one extra line for the definition of the `cmp` variable, plus one extra line for the separate `std::sort` call.

Comment: my app is based on FLTK, which doesn't do string.

Comment: you're right about even more code, but there's a fine line between too many lines and too-long lines

Comment: You can still use `std::string` in your code. When passing it to a C function then use the `c_str()` member function to get a `const char*`. And when fetching a string from the framework, then just assign it to your `std::string` object. Yes it might complicate things when interfacing with the framework, but hopefully that's only a small part of your code, and the larger and more important parts of your code will become much easier and better.

Comment: i might try that at some point but processing widget labels *is* a huge part of the app, including the keyboard handler which already has a pretty big workload.